# Blurry product images in wordpress - woocommerce

Tags: wordpress

I am using the Mystile theme in Wordpress and woocommerce for the shop, and i think there is a setting or piece of code that is causing my images to blur.

See my site:
http://www.skinmade.com.au/products-page/

The thumbnails are blurry, but if you click into a product and then click on the product image to enlarge, it is not blurry.

I have seen a few posts saying you need to change the css to `width:100%` but can't find where to do this.

Comment: Your images are scaled. Your original pictures seem to be 150px x 150px, your width:100% probably goes for .attachment-shop_catalog.wp-post-image

Comment: @emartel i uploaded the images at 1250x1250. there are lots on different posts on advice on what to do. nothing has worked for me though

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not a web designer so I won't post a "real answer".  Take a look at http://www.skinmade.com.au/wp-content/themes/mystile/style.css and http://www.skinmade.com.au/wp-content/themes/mystile/style.css that's where the problem lies. I suspect the `height: auto;` to be the problem

Comment: ok thanks. and should i delete it? or replace it with something else?

Comment: The easiest solution would possibly to hire somebody who knows about CSS to fix your issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. This happens because the default images size in Mystile are different from de default images size in WooCommerce options. The Mystile theme uses 162 x 162 pixels for "Catalog Thumbs" and 510 x 510 pixels for "Single Thumbs". Just go to WooCommerce -> Settings -> Catalog, an change these values.

Important: You'll need the [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin, to fix the images you already have uploaded. Also uncheck the "Hard Crop" option.

Hope this helps!